# Convert ninject membershipreboot to Autofac

Tags: c#, ninject, autofac

I am playing with the membership reboot provider and have found an example of the code but using Ninject instead of Autofac.

Could someone please help me convert the Ninject stuff into Autofac:

```
kernel.Bind<MembershipRebootConfiguration<CustomUserAccount>>().ToConstant(config);

kernel.Bind<IUserAccountRepository<CustomUserAccount>>().To<CustomRepository>()
    .InRequestScope();
kernel.Bind<CustomDatabase>().ToSelf().InRequestScope();
kernel.Bind<IUserAccountQuery>().To<CustomRepository>().InRequestScope();
kernel.Bind<AuthenticationService<CustomUserAccount>>()
    .To<SamAuthenticationService<CustomUserAccount>>();
```

I only know how to modify one of them

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
builder.RegisterType<CustomRepository>().As<IUserAccountQuery>()
    .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```

Once I have it working I will submit it to the guys working on MRB to maybe help someone else out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the Autofac docu, I'd translate it like this:

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

builder.RegisterInstance(config)
    .As<MembershipRebootConfiguration<CustomUserAccount>>();
builder.RegisterType<CustomRepository>()
    .As<IUserAccountRepository<CustomUserAccount>>()
    .InstancePerRequest();
builder.RegisterType<CustomDatabase>()
    .AsSelf()
    .InstancePerRequest();
builder.RegisterType<CustomRepository>()
    .As<IUserAccountQuery>()
    .InstancePerRequest();
builder.RegisterType<SamAuthenticationService<CustomUserAccount>>()
    .As<AuthenticationService<CustomUserAccount>>();
```

note that I used `InstancePerRequest()` which probably requires you to add a corresponding NuGet package for the ASP.NET edition you're using (so does Ninject when using `InRequestScope()`).